# Boolean 2d array of size m by n, another integer 2d array also with size m by n, and another integer 2d array of size r by c, replace values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, boolean

I am trying to code a reverse tetris game for fun, but I am stumped on a part of my implementation :(
So I have a boolean 2D array of size m by n, another integer 2D array representing the field also of size m by n, and another integer 2D array of size r by c (the tetris piece).

Example:
Game field:
int[][] field =  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{1, 1, 0, 1, 0},{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}};

Tetris piece:
int[][] figure = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};

Boolean 2d Array: (Wrote code for this)
boolean[][] fieldbool = [[true, true, true, true, true], [true, true, true, true, true], [true, true, true, true, true], [false, false, true, true, true], [false, false, false, true, false]]

Expected output:
final field matrix
int[][] field =  {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0},{1, 0, 1, 0, 0},{1, 0, 1, 0, 0},{1, 1, 0, 1, 0},{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}};

I want to fit the tetris piece in the smallest row and column index possible. I am super confused on how to do this. Worked on it for four hours and still stumped :(

So far, I tried maintaining two integer variables that store count for the number of times there is true for row and for col. If the count is equal to the height/width of the tetris piece, I have a for loop that goes back from the index currently in minus that count and fill the values in the field. It's not working as I my output is the same as the given field.

Comment: 1) What is "reverse Tetris"?  2) I understand the game field and figure (piece) arrays.  What does the boolean array do?  3) Edit your question to include a [mre] as text that we can copy into our IDE, compile, run, and test.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.